# Can you eradicate barbarians completely in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm at peace with all my neighbors.

I thought: hm. Let me just get rid all the barbarians so I can focus on space race. I got rid of two barbarian outposts. Then one spawned. Then another barbarian outpost spawned. Now there are FOUR barbarian outposts.

The eradicating the first three barbarian outposts was easy... I have guns they have clubs (musketmen, infantry, rangers vs warriors and archers).

But now that I have nuclear tech... The barbarians are spawning NUCLEAR SUBMARINES. It took 3-4 naval ships to take out their nuclear submarine.

### Can you eradicate barbarians completely?

I ask because everytime I destroy one barbarian outpost 1-2 barbarian outposts spawn.

It's really getting tiresome. I have spent now about 30+ turns and like 5-10+ hours.

Do I need to create nukes and just nuke all of them in one turn to prevent them spawning?

Comment: I believe that the game tries to keep some number of barbarian outputs and will spawn the new ones in the fog of war once the old ones are cleared out. But if you are starting a new game, you can configure it to have no barbarians

Answer (score 13):

https://civ6.gamepedia.com/Barbarian

Barbarians can spawn throughout the duration of the game in the "fog of war" area; that is, tiles which no civ or city-state has vision of.

So to keep Barbarians from spawning, you'd need to put cities/scouts/other units in those "dark" areas of the map where there are no civs or city-states.  Once the whole map is covered by the vision of at least one civ or city-state, barbarianism will cease.

Comment: Note that this doesn't account for rebels that can spawn in a city through espionage. They technically count as barbarian units, though they have no encampment.